# How to perform the sum operation grouping by some fields when the input is in CSV format in Mule?

Tags: sum, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

When the `location` and `gl` fields contains the same values we need to perform the sum operation for the amount and the input is as follows:

```
location,gl,amt
1,11,1
1,11,2
1,12,1
1,12,2
2,11,1
2,12,2
```

The required output is as follows:

```
[
{
"loc": "1",
"gl": "11",
"amt": 3
},
{
"loc": "1",
"gl": "12",
"amt": 3
},
{
"loc": "2",
"gl": "11",
"amt": "1"
},
{
"loc": "2",
"gl": "12",
"amt": "2"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the grouping really requires more than one level (location and gl) I have this convoluted answer. There may some way to simplify it.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
flatten((payload groupBy ($.location) mapObject (value, key) -> (
  (key): value groupBy ($.gl) pluck 
    ($$): $.amt map ($ as Number)

)) pluck ((value1, key1, index1) -> value1 map ($ mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {
    location: key1,
    gl: key,
    amt: sum(value)
  }))))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "location": "1",
    "gl": "11",
    "amt": 3
  },
  {
    "location": "1",
    "gl": "12",
    "amt": 3
  },
  {
    "location": "2",
    "gl": "11",
    "amt": 1
  },
  {
    "location": "2",
    "gl": "12",
    "amt": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the `groupBy` with two fields by using string interpolation, then use `pluck` to create an array of array's that contain grouped records. Then I `flatMap` through the collection, I set `loc` and `gl` using the first records in that collection since those values aren't expected to change, then use `sum()` to add together the amount array

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var groupedRecords = payload groupBy "$($.location)-$($.gl)" pluck $
---
groupedRecords flatMap (item) -> do {
    var firstItem = item[0]
    var amtArr = item.amt
    ---
    {
        loc:  firstItem.location,
        gl:   firstItem.gl,
        amt:  sum(amtArr)
    }
}
```